# Installing IE 11 onto VMware fusion w/ Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm a tech at my school's helpdesk and I'm running into this strange issue.

I've already installed all possible Windows Updates. I can't seem to remove IE 10 from the computer. When I attempt to run the update for IE 11 and when I try to download it and run the executable myself, it gets to about halfway before saying the update did not install.

Already tried removing firewall as well, and running it in Safe mode.

Comment: What error is it giving for the install failure? Have you tried looking in the EventViewer? If so are there any relevant entries?

Comment: I am pretty sure IE10 is required to update to IE11

Comment: Reset Windows update (stop it, delete SoftwareDistribution folder, start it again), try again.  And/or try it from a direct download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/ie.aspx?q=internet+explorer

Answer (score 0):

> I've already installed all possible Windows Updates.

Ofc. That is a given for every computer connected to the internet. Not to do that is utter insanity for a school envirnment.

> I can't seem to remove IE 10 from the computer.

Correct. IE is not a separate program on windows. It is tightly woven into the OS. You can literally not remove all part, so there is no uninstall.

> When I attempt to run the update for IE 11 and when I try to download it and run the executable myself, it gets to about halfway before saying the update did not install.

OK, the bigh question is now: Why did it now install. Did it log a reason in a log file. Did it pop up a message with only the text "Update did not install" or did it given more clues in the popup.

Find the reason and fix it, then do the upgrade.

> Already tried removing firewall as well, and running it in Safe mode.

Why would removing the firewall have any influence. You already wrote that other windows updates were installed fine, so the connection is working fine. No firewall is interfering with that.

Instead try this:

1. Clean shutdown and boot of the VM. (No reboot!)
2. Checking log files in the event viewer (start run eventvwr.msc)
3. Optionally clean the  SoftwareDistribution directory. (start, run, net stop wuauserv,  go to %windir%\SoftwareDistribution and delete all content. Then net start wuauserv and try the updates again).